# How to add data from one table to another using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a student table and a mentor table. Each student will have one mentor assigned to them. So, I want to assign random mentor's ID to each student. How can I do this??

My student model:

```
 mentor: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    ref: 'Mentor' 
 }
```

Comment: so you want to update your data base or you will assign when insert new student doc ?

Comment: For now, I want to insert data not update the data.

Comment: could you define what the inverse relationship is going to be? will each mentor have one student? could a single mentor due to random draws have all students assigned?

Comment: get list of mentor's ids at the start of application and same in object or array and randomly when you want to insert student add new id , if you want i write its code

Comment: Each mentor can have multiple students but each student can have one mentor.

Comment: Could you please write the code and post it here?